# spring boot dynamic JPA queries

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have some queries like like below

```
@Query(value="select userid from user_info where name=?1 and phone=?2)
List<Integer> findUserBynameAndPhone(String userName, String userPhone);
```

will these query translated to select userid from user_info where name=userName and phone=userPhone ..

How to understand these kind of queries which have  ?0 ?1 etc

Comment: what do you mean with `How to interpret the dynamic queries`?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: yes, index parameters will work as you would expect, see here for example https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter#Ordinal_Parameters_index